# _this2.pressRow is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to learn React Native and am currently trying to create a list view. The everything is loading fine, this issue comes on the press of a row where I get the following error.

[image]

I come from a web and objective-c background so this is taking a little time to sink in. This is the code Im using for the screen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native'

export default class FeedView extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Chat with Feed',
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this._renderRow}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _renderRow( rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number, highlightRow: (sectionID: number, rowID: number) => void ){
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
          this._pressRow(rowID);
          highlightRow(sectionID, rowID);
        }}>
        <View>
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Testing</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

  _pressRow( rowID: number ){

  }

}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#F6F6F6',
  }
});
```

Comment: i think you forgot to `bind` this method `renderRow={this._renderRow}` try this: `renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}`

Comment: Thanks guys for the info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments and above, you need to bind your ES6 class methods with `this` if you want access to the `this` variable in other methods, as they do not autobind.

I would suggest putting all the bindings in your constructor, as it is considered good practice (reduce garbage collection) and makes your code neater. See the relevant [ESLint page](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#es6-classes) for more information.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    ...

    this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);
    this._pressRow = this._pressRow.bind(this);
}
```

You can then just use `this._renderRow` on its own within your class without worrying about binding.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this` in your `renderRow` function doesn't refer to the `context of the React Component` and hence you are not able to access the `_pressRow` function

You need to bind the `renderRow` function

```
render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={() => this._renderRow()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```